# Kubernetes настройка реплик

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Есть проект, которое состоит из двух Docker контейнеров: приложения и redis. Проект развернут в Kubernetes. Как сделать, чтобы приложение могло иметь несколько экземпляров, но redis всегда был один?

Comment: у деплоимента увеличить количество реплик?

Comment: @ExplodingKitten тогда увеличится количество реплик пода. А как быть, если внутри пода есть redis, который должен быть всегда один и общим для всех подов?

Comment: не делать его внутри пода, запускать отдельно redis и отдельно ваше приложение

Answer (score 0):

Запускать redis отдельно, как Statefulset object.